Not understanding a step of Stokes’ Theorem's proof in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds
I'm struggling to understand a step in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. When proving Stokes’ Theorem for the case $M = \mathbb{H}^n$ (page 413), he writes: $\def\HH{\mathbb{H}}\def\w{\omega}\def\dx{\text{d}x}\def\f{\varphi}$
$$\int_{\partial\HH^n}\w = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{A\cap\partial\HH^n}\w\left(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1},0\right)\dx^1\wedge\stackrel{\widehat{i}}{\cdots}\wedge\dx^n.$$
As $\w$ is supported on $A$, it's natural to only pay attention to $A\cap\partial\HH^n$. However, I'm confused as to why the equality above holds.

First of all, by definition of an integral on a manifold, we have
$$\int_{\partial\HH^n}\w = \int_{\f(U)}(\f^{-1})^*\w$$
where $(U,\f)$ is a smooth chart on $\partial \HH^n$ containing the support of $\w$. This fact seems crucial, but is never explicitly used.

Secondly, where is the fact that $\w$ "is to be interpreted as $\iota^*_{\partial\HH^n}\w$" (stated in the remark right after Stokes’ Theorem) used?



As to your second point, formally speaking an expression of the form
$$
    \int_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n} \omega
$$
needs some exegesis: $\omega$ is a form on $\mathbb{H}^n$ on $\mathbb{H}^n$, not on $\partial \mathbb{H}^n$. The definition of integral, however, demands that you only try to integrate forms of degree matching the dimension of the manifold defined on that manifold, so you need to do something to $\omega$, and the obvious thing to do is to simply restrict it to $\partial \mathbb{H}^n$, which is the same as pulling it back along $\iota_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n}$ (see the discussion after Proposition 16.5, page 406 in my edition where this is first defined).
About your first point: It is crucial for doing explicit calculations, but by this point Lee has established enough properties of the integral to be able to do most work just manipulating forms, as evidenced by the proof. In fact, the proof does make use of this definition, just below the section you're asking about, but it's not what does the heavy lifting.
Finally, for the equality you're struggling with, note that
$$
    \omega(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \omega_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n
$$
as presented on the previous page, so using the remark about your second point, we find that
\begin{align}
    \int_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n} \omega &= \int_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n} \iota_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n}^* \omega \\
    &= \int_{A \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n} \iota_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n}^* \omega \qquad\qquad\text{($\omega$ supported on $A$)} \\
    &= \int_{A \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \omega_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, 0) dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n \\
    &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{A \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n} \omega_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, 0) dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n
\end{align}
using that $\iota_{\partial \mathbb{H}^n}(x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}) = (x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, 0)$.
